# Troubleshooting: Unable to Attach EFS Volume with Weaviate Pod in Amazon EKS

Tags: amazon-eks, eksctl, weaviate

pv.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: efs-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 32Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: fs-0109b7cba15479c81
```

storageClass.yaml

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: efs-sc
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
```

claim.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: efs-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

When I tried to attach the persistent volume claim with two test pods, it was working, but when I tried to use it in the weaviate, I am getting the following error,

made these modification in the values.yaml pulled from here, https://github.com/weaviate/weaviate-helm/blob/master/weaviate/values.yaml

```
# The Persistent Volume Claim settings for Weaviate. If there's a
# storage.fullnameOverride field set, then the default pvc will NOT be
# created, instead the one defined in fullnameOverride will be used
storage:
  fullnameOverride: efs-claim
  storageClassName: efs-sc
```

I tried everything, including chatgpt, I can use the Newly created EFS volume in two different pods, and I can see the data being persistent from both of them,
But the I want to know why I can't connect it with weaviate as mentioned in the values.yaml?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Not that it should matter, but it looks like the PVC in the StatefulSet is configured to use RWO instead of RWM.

Comment: @JeremyCowan I am declaring any access mode for statefulset, can you please elobarete your solution?

Comment: The chart (default values) is configured to use RWO not RWM. Does the application support RWM?